# Sending email notification in Django

Tags: django, django-email

I'm building a simple blog application. I have my blog up and running on development server. Now I wish to send mail to all the subscribers every time a new blog post is created by me/ admin. I know to use Django's sending_email library but I can't figure out how to automate the process, i.e, how to send the email using send_email() automatically every time I create another ' blog_post' object?

**Note** :  I'm creating new 'blog_post'objects using Django's admin interface, so basically when I 'save' the object, I want to send the email.

I'm new to Django, any suggestion, guidance would be of great help

Code below : 
signals.py

```
@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Post)
def send_post_mail(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print('signal send')
    subject = "Thank you for registering with us"
    send_mail(subject, 'Body', 'sender@gmail.com', 
    ['reciever@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False,)
```

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published'),
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, 
                        unique = True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                           related_name='blog_posts', 
 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
audio = models.URLField(max_length = 200, default = 
"spotify:episode:0Vbl7RvX3KE0lSkRmy9Wjj") 
body = models.TextField()
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

apps.py

```
    from django.apps import AppConfig


   class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
         name = 'blog'


         def ready(self):
         import blog.signals
```

views.py

```
     def post_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.order_by('-publish')
        return render(request, 'template.html', context = {'post':posts})
```

blog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
#path('', views.Postlist, name='main-view'),
path('', views.get_name, name='main-form-view'),
path('<slug:slug>', views.detail_post, name='detail-post')
```

]

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sender@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'seder's account password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

init.py

```
default_app_config = 'blog.apps.BlogConfig'
```

**Edit** :  It worked after configuring app.py and init.py as shown above.

Comment: Have you tried signals?

Comment: Check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/

Comment: @HeisAif, Thanks for the quick response. The issue with signals is that I'm using Django's admin interface to create and save the object.  If I had created another form explicitly, then I could create an instance of that form and use signals to send mail every time it got invoked but like I said I'm using Django's admin's interface here

Comment: What is the model for blog post? You can use signals when models are created even if created from admin interface.

Comment: Okay so I have a model called ' blog_post ' with 4 fields in it. Then I create the blog_posts objects using admin's interface and then using views I get all the blog_posts objects created and display them on my site. I know to use signals with forms that I create but how to use signals when I'm creating object from admin's site ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a file with name signals.py in same folder as your models.py.
2. Add following imports to signals.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models import signals
from .models import Blog_post
```

3. Create a method and use your email library

```
@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Blog_post)
def send_mail(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # to test if the signal is working
    print('signal send')
    # replace it with your code once it works
```

4. Add signals to apps.py in same folder as your models.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'yourapp'

    # Add this to use signals
    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. I tried this but doesn't seem to work. I have neither received the mail nor the the print message on object creation. I have added necessary code snippets, let me  know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: First try to get the signals working, then you can make it work with emails.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send emails to all subscribers use signal like this:

```
You can create a signal in blog post view like this:

@receiver(post_save, sender=BlogPost)
def send_mail_to_subs(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for subs in instance.author.subscribed.all():
            send_mail(
                f'New Post from {instance.author}',
                f'Title: {instance.post_title}',
                'youremail',
                [subs.email],
            )
```

Good coding :)